# Analyzing Wav file format

Tags: matlab, audio, wav, file-format

I need to separate data and Subchunk2Size in a Wav file.
I'm trying to use a ready code for this part of my MATLAB code but I can't understand what's going on here. 
This is my source for analyzing a Wav file. [enter link description here](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/)
In this part, I understand that the 40bytes header is stored in `header`.

```
 %first 40 bytes make wav header,store the header
    header=fread(fid,40);
```

My problem is here with `Subchunk2Size` . It's 4 bytes but here we are reading `1`. When I use 4 I get a wrong result.

```
 %41st byte to 43rd byte,length of wav data samples 
    data_size=fread(fid,1);
```

I can't understand this part either.

```
  %copy the 16 bit wav data samples starting from 44th byte
    [dta,count]=fread(fid,inf,'uint16');
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `fread` is a dimension, not a size. Use the third argument instead.

Comment: Can you explain more please?